# SQL - dropping multiple columns with a WHILE loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to drop many columns with the name `Column x` where `x` is a number from 20 all the way to 100.

I'm trying to use this code:

```
DECLARE @cnt CHAR = 20;

WHILE @cnt < 101
BEGIN
   ALTER TABLE dbo.CSP_Collection_CSV DROP COLUMN "Column " + @cnt;
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```

But I get an error near the `+` sign

> Incorrect syntax near '+'

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a **numerical** value (like 1, 2, ...., 20), you should use an `INT` datatype (**not** `CHAR` - furthermore, defining a `CHAR` *without* an explicit length defines a string of **exactly 1 character length** - typically *not* what you want - get in the habit of **always** explicitly defining a length for any `CHAR`, `VARCHAR` etc. string types!).

Also: if you want to combine string and int, you need to cast the int to a string explicitly - T-SQL doesn't do this implicitly for you.

And to finish off: you need to use *dynamic SQL* to handle this situation - you cannot define a column name that you want to drop without resorting to dynamic SQL.

Try this code:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 20;
DECLARE @DropStmt NVARCHAR(500);

WHILE @cnt < 101
BEGIN
    SET @DropStmt = N'ALTER TABLE dbo.CSP_Collection_CSV ' + 
                    N'DROP COLUMN "Column ' + CAST(@cnt AS NVARCHAR(3)) + '";';

    EXEC (@DropStmt);

    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks but i'm getting the same error.. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Comment: @gambit20088: you need to use dynamic SQL - updated my response

Comment: I'm getting `Must declare the scalar variable "@DropStat".`